# What does XF86Mail and XF86WWW correspond to in Xfce4?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, settings

In the default shortcuts of Xfce4 there is commands affected to the following shortcut: "XF86Mail" and "XF86WWW".

[image]

What do they correspond to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the source code of file [`XF86keysym.h`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/tree/XF86keysym.h), and [this table](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols) it seems to be exactly what the name suppose to be in a very suggestive way: The keyboard symbols to "Mail" and "Internet"(some of them have the "E" of Internet Explorer printed on it):

```
#define XF86XK_Mail     0x1008FF19   /* Invoke user's mail program */
#define XF86XK_WWW      0x1008FF2E   /* Invoke web browser         */
```

Answer (score 1):

They correspond to dedicated keys available on some keyboards, typically in a cluster of “multimedia” keys (see for example [this Microsoft keyboard with “email and internet hot keys”](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/business/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000-for-business/5qh-00001#specsColumns-testCarousel)); `XF86Mail` is the key assigned to access email, `XF86WWW` the key assigned to start a web browser.